# Leafletでマップに追加したマーカーを消す方法

Tags: javascript, leaflet

```
onMapMoved = function(e) {
  map.removeLayer(markerList);
  var url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
  var searchKeywords = get_search_keywords();

  if (searchKeywords.length > 0) {
      searchKeywords.forEach(function output(searchKeywords) {
          since_id = null;
          getTwitter(url, searchKeywords);
      });
  }
};
```

地図上に追加されたマーカーを消す実装をonMapMoved関数に追加したいと考えているのですが、どなたかその方法を知っている方、回答お願い致します。

(get_search_keywords関数はウェブページで検索したいキーワードを選択させたものを解釈して配列に、その配列に入っているキーワード分getTwitter関数に渡して実際にツイートを検索しています。getした情報を基に違う関数で地図に緯度経度情報を持つものだけマーカープロットしている状況です。)

地図にプロットしている関数のコードはこちら

```
function update(data) { // 引数(data)に取得したデータが入ってくる
var bounds, distance1, distance2, r, southWest;
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var center = bounds.getCenter();
var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
var distance1 = bounds.getNorthWest().distanceTo(southWest) / 1000;
var distance2 = bounds.getSouthEast().distanceTo(southWest) / 1000;
var r = distance1 < distance2 ? distance1 : distance2;
r *= 0.5;
r = Math.floor(r * 10) / 10;

$("#tweetDisplay").empty(); // 表示エリアを空にする
$("#tweetDisplay").append('<br>');
var geoFlag = 0;

$("#tweetDisplay").append("<p style='border: medium solid'>Twitter (地図中央から半径" + r + "km)</p>");

var result = data.statuses; // 取得したデータから、メソッドチェーンで必要なものを取得

// TwitterからGeoタグを保有しているTweetだった場合のみ緯度経度を取得して、地図にマーカープロット
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var name = result[i].user.name; // ツイートした人の名前
    var account = result[i].user.screen_name; // ツイートした人のアカウント名
    var imgsrc = result[i].user.profile_image_url; // ツイートした人のプロフィール画像
    // var content = result[i].text; // ツイートの内容
    var contents = AutoLink(result[i].text); // ツイート内にURLがあればリンクへ飛ぶ
    var updated = result[i].created_at; // ツイートした時間

    var tweet;

    // Tweet表示エリアに取得したデータを追加していく
    tweet = "<a href='https://twitter.com/" + account + "'><img src='"
            + imgsrc + "'></a>" + "<p>" + 'ID: ' + name + ' @' + account
            + "<br>" + contents + "<br>";

    if (result[i].coordinates) {
        geoFlag = 1;
        var coordinates = result[i].coordinates.coordinates; // ツイートの緯度経度情報
        tweet += '緯度: ' + coordinates[1] + ', 経度: ' + coordinates[0]
                + "<br>" + 'Time: ' + updated + "<br></p>";
        $("#tweetDisplay").append(tweet);
        var icon = L.icon({
            iconUrl : imgsrc,
            iconSize : [ 20, 22 ]
        });
        marker = L.marker([ coordinates[1], coordinates[0] ], {
            icon : icon
        }).addTo(map);
        markerList.push(marker);
    } else {
        tweet += 'Time: ' + updated + "<br></p>";
        $("#tweetDisplay").append(tweet);
    }
    if (i != count - 1) {
        $("#tweetDisplay").append("</p><hr noshade size='7'>");
    }
}
if (geoFlag === 0) {
    alert('Geoタグ付きツイートは検出されませんでした。');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`onMapMoved`は正規のメソッドではないのでソースコードの提示が欲しいところですが･･･
`removeLayer`を使います。

```
var marker = L.marker([ latitude, longitude ] {
    icon : icon
}).addTo(map);

function onMapMoved() {
    map.removeLayer(marker);
}

map.on('move', onMapMoved);
```

Comment: 返答が遅れてしまって申し訳ありません。
お聞きしたい事はonMapMovedが正規のメソッドではないとはどういうことでしょう。また、どの部分のソースコードがを提示したらよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: `leaflet`に`onMapMoved`というメソッドはありませんよね？定義しなければいけない関数で、かつ質問文に含む(しかも`onMapMoved`関数へのロジック追加を依頼している)のであれば`onMapMoved`関数を記載した方が分かりやすい良いですよ、ということです。

Comment: kotatsuさん
なるほど、そういうことですね。ご意見ありがとうございます。早速追加いたします。